Can "date + にも" mean "as soon as"?
This article from NHK News Web Easy has the following sentence:

環境省は、今年7月にも会議を開いて、法律を変えるための準備をする予定です。

Based on my understanding that も roughly means "even," my naïve translation is that there will be a meeting "even in July of this year." This implies to me that this is somehow surprising—maybe meetings don't usually happen in July for some reason? ChatGPT and Google Translate both translate it differently, instead saying "as early as July of this year." Is this a valid translation?
I kinda see the logic of using も here, if the implication is that these meetings usually take a long time to plan. But, in English I feel like this would be made much more explicit. Of course, Japanese might be different in this regard, so is it a reasonable default to translate "<date> + にも" to mean "as soon as <date>"?

I think this も simply means "also" as the article says 環境省は、この法律について話し合う会議を開きました just before that line.

@aguijonazo I see! Does that imply that the rest of the sentence (法律を変える…) applies to the first meeting as well?

No, it doesn't. 7月にも simply modifies 開く. The rest of the sentence explains what they will do in the July meeting. They might or might have done the same thing in the first meeting.

も means either "also" or "even", so 7月にも会議を開く can mean either of the following:

again in July; also in July
as early as July (i.e., July is an impressively early option, but it can happen in July at the earliest)

In your article, 7月にも simply means "again in July", because the article says that one meeting for this issue has already been held.
When も means "even" rather than "also", it's safe to translate 7月にも as "as early as July", like ChatGPT and Google Translate did. The も is used to suggest that July is an impressively early option, so the background is indeed "it doesn't usually happen in July because it takes some time to plan it". Note that saying 7月にも会議を開く does not rule out the possibility that it will happen later, like in August. も is just one character, but I think this nuance is explicit enough. To express "in July at the earliest" more matter-of-factly, we say 早くて7月に.

I don't quite follow how this meaning arises. It would make sense to me if the verb were in potential form.

@KarlKnechtel Which meaning? The literal meaning ("even in July") suggests it's a surprisingly early option, so are you asking about the former meaning?

I mean that "even in July" and "also in July" are different ideas in English. Without context, OP's original interpretation (something like "the meeting wouldn't normally happen in July, but this year it's happening every month") makes about as much sense to me.

@KarlKnechtel Ah, sorry, I assumed the meeting in July was the first meeting, but after reading the article carefully, "also in July" is the valid translation here. I'll edit.

The answer to the question in the title is yes, although I would say it's closer to "as early as" than to "as soon as."
However, it doesn't mean that in your sentence. The article mentions they have already had one meeting just before that sentence.

環境省は、この法律について話し合う会議を開きました。専門家や警察が出席しました。そして、町で熊の被害が出る心配があるときなどには、銃を使うことができるように法律を変える案を出しました。
環境省は、今年7月にも会議を開いて、法律を変えるための準備をする予定です。

It would make more sense to understand that the last sentence simply says they will hold a similar meeting in July, too, especially when the article is supposed to be written in easy Japanese for learners.
In general, も puts what it marks (i.e. what comes before it) into the same group as some other things. The sense of "even" arises when the thing thus included is something you would normally expect to be outside of the group. Often times, what other things form the target group is not explicitly mentioned, but by specifically including something in it, your listener will feel the presence of a boundary and see the thing included within it. I think the sense of "as early as" arises from this feeling of "within" when （に）も is applied to a particular date and the unstated target group is understood as being formed by all possible dates when something can happen. I think this tends to be used when something is already known to happen. A typhoon hitting the land is a typical example.

台風7号は15日にも本州に上陸する見込みだ。

There is nothing "impressive" about the typhoon arriving on the 15th.
In your sentence, the target "group" is formed by the first meeting they have already had to discuss the same matter.
